# Conflict on c++ standard with cmake

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cmake, c++14

I'm having some issues with setting the C++ standard for my project built with CMake. The code heavily uses C++11 features, so up to now I was doing:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Now, since recent GCC versions use C++14 by default, I end up having to link with libraries built with C++14 as public requirement, and there is a conflict when trying to build using strictly C++11.

So, the goal is to require **at least** the C++11 standard, but using the default compiler version if it is more recent.

I've tried with

```
target_compile_features(myLib PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

but CMake ends up adding the `-std=c++11` flag, which is confusing because the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html) explictly says

> CMake will ensure the compiler is invoked in a mode that is aware of C++ 11 (or above), adding flags such as -std=gnu++11 if necessary

I've also tried using the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_COMPUTED_DEFAULT` internal variable, but that is cumbersome since `"98"` is greater than `"11"`.

It is certainly possible to get it working using that variable or using the `check_cxx_compiler_flag()` function, and testing the different cases, but I was hoping that there would be a simpler way to achieve this in a day and age where new standards arrive every three years...

Comment: I think the modern way is to not specify the standard but [every feature you use (... yeah)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html). With a bit of luck cmake will deduce the minimal standard you want while allowing higher standards if they also support the features you use.

Comment: @nwp This is actually more like a dinosaur way. Seems to be the same nightmare as feature check macros in autotools...

Comment: @VTT I agree that it's a terrible way of doing things, but it's cmake we are talking about. And [I didn't just make this up](https://youtu.be/HPMvU64RUTY?t=4m48s).

Comment: @nwp Right, that would probably be the most "correct" way, but it's clearly not practical to implement for an already existing project... Since the code heavily uses C++11 features, it would be a pain to go through them all.

Comment: You can just require lambdas which gives you C++11 and not actually list every feature. It might create issues with people using VS2010 which does have lambdas but not all of C++11, but if you don't support that compiler it's probably fine.

Comment: This actually sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): *"there is a conflict when trying to build using strictly C++11"*: Something in your compiler toolchain broke and you are hacking around the bug instead of fixing it. Maybe you should fix your toolchain instead so it can compile with the standard you are using.

Comment: @nwp Thanks, that might just work.
Well, in this case problem X is not under my control: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1351623

Comment: @nwp I've tried adding `cxx_lambdas` (and a few others). That doesn't work either: cmake adds the C++11 flag even when I'm testing with GCC 7.2 (default=C++14)...

Comment: There are some cmake files somewhere that defined which compiler has which flags for which features. Maybe it makes sense to edit that file on redhat so that it never uses C++11. That way you can leave your CMakeLists.txt as is and circumvent the bug. Might be worth considering to add to redhat's repository.

Comment: Sorry, that's not going to cut it... Guess I'll revert to using `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_COMPUTED_DEFAULT` and checking the different cases.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but anyways: You are on the right path, just use `target_compile_features` for the libraries you declare in your CMakeLists projects. There should be no problem linking a c++14 library with a c++11 library if you are using the **same GCC version** (it doesn't matter what -std=... do you put on each library).

So, if you have libA, libB and libC and you can just do this:

```
target_compile_features(libA PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_features(libB PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
target_compile_features(libC PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

If for some reason the compiler version needed to be different, then I guess you should be able to link them if you can build shared libraries instead of static libraries.

Further clarification regarding cxx extensions and standard:
If extensions want to be avoided (ie compiling with c++11 instead of gnu++11) one could set CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Default behavior is to have CXX extensions enabled. You need to set this before the target is created.

Simple example without extensions allowed:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(test-poc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

we add CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF before creating the target, so CMake will choose -std=c++17 instead of -std=gnu++17. If we remove that line, CMake will chose -std=gnu++17

See:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_EXTENSIONS.html#prop_tgt:CXX_EXTENSIONS

Comment: Please clarify the answer as to `cxx_std_11` imply cxx extensions or not (`gnu++11` vs `c++11` gcc flag)

Comment: see the edited response. If cmake is using gnu compiler (ie gcc) it will default to use the extensions (gnu+11 gnu++14 and so on). If you want to restrict to use only the standard, you need to specify set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) before creating the target.